# Is there a method to get BetterDiscord to autoupdate with Discord?

Tags: plugins, discord

BetterDiscord is a plugin system for Discord that allows me to do some really cool stuff: I have to have [`EditUsers`](https://betterdiscord.app/plugin/EditUsers) which allows me to rename users h4x0r names to their real names: without this I'll never remember the names of the people I'm talking to.

One problem with BetterDiscord is every Discord updates to another version Discord will redownload the new version. Then when it reboots BetterDiscord is uninstalled. I have to re-download it here,

- https://betterdiscord.app/

Then I have to `chmod +x` the installer, and rerun it, and then kill and restart Discord. Since Discord now updates once a week, is there a faster method of doing this? Is there like an auto-updater for BetterDiscord?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No Solution Yet

There is currently no solution.

https://github.com/BetterDiscord/BetterDiscord/issues/1231

Answer (score 0):

I also got bored of reinstalling BetterDiscord 100 times, so i made not big script to make this routine automatic. (Only for Windows for now :S)

https://github.com/Zwylair/BetterDiscordAutoInstaller

Comment: Please explain what your script does, perhaps provide screenshots and do read the help on self-promotion.

Comment: Updated, thanks. Where can i get this help page?